# MSVC function matching with const enum value 0

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was bitten by an unintended C++ function match by MSVC. I can reduce it to the following test case:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Code { aaa, bbb };

struct MyVal {
    Code c;
    MyVal(Code c): c(c) { }
};

void test(int i, MyVal val) {
    std::cout << "case " << i << ": value " << val.c << std::endl;
}

void test(int i, double* f) {
    std::cout << "case " << i << ": WRONG" << std::endl;
}

const Code v1 = aaa;
      Code v2 = aaa;
const Code v3 = bbb;

int main() {
    const Code w1 = aaa;
          Code w2 = aaa;
    const Code w3 = bbb;

    test(1, v1);  // unexpected MSVC WRONG
    test(2, v2);
    test(3, v3);
    test(4, aaa);
    test(5, w1);  // unexpected MSVC WRONG
    test(6, w2);
    test(7, w3);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that all 7 invocations of test would match the first overload, and GCC ([live example](http://rextester.com/TOCI97245)) and Clang ([live example](http://rextester.com/TIVB97417)) match this as intended:

```
case 1: value 0
case 2: value 0
case 3: value 1
case 4: value 0
case 5: value 0
case 6: value 0
case 7: value 1
```

But MSVC ([live example](http://rextester.com/NFW8886)) matches cases 1 and 5 to the "wrong" overload (I found this behavior in MSVC 2013 and 2015):

```
case 1: WRONG
case 2: value 0
case 3: value 1
case 4: value 0
case 5: WRONG
case 6: value 0
case 7: value 1
```

It seems that the conversion to a pointer is preferred by MSVC for a const enum variable with (accidental) value 0. I would have expected this behavior with a literal 0, but not with an enum variable.

My questions: Is the MSVC behavior standard-conformant? (Perhaps for an older version of C++?) If not, is this a known extension or bug?

Comment: How about editing your question and include the output of your code, for completeness?

Comment: `v1` is clearly of type `Code`, it is a bug of msvc.

Comment: @Jarod42: The question is whether a null pointer constant matches `double*` better than it matches a user-defined conversion. `test` doesn't take a `Code` so I don't think it's quite that clear-cut.

Comment: GCC and Clang what? In what standard mode?

Comment: C++14 introduced a change to null pointer constants, basically requiring that the value be a literal in order to qualify. However, GCC gives me those "expected" results even in C++03 mode so that change may not be enough to explain this.

Comment: Can someone clarify what the question is? You have `MyVal` and `double*` types yet you pass an enum, I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @RawN: GCC and Clang prefer the conversion to `MyVal` in all cases. MSVS prefers treating the enum value 0 as a null pointer constant in the case when the enum value 0 is `const` (derp)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Also happens in VC 2010 that does not have the C++ 11 support.

Comment: @RawN: It would be the other way around - VC not yet having support for this C++11 or C++14 change (not entirely sure which it is at present)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see. Thanks for the info. I think the OP should update the question.

Comment: @RawN: The question already says this.

Comment: What happens in MSVC is that you are passing an enum of value 0 (zero) (aaa), that's treated as a null pointer, thus MSVC consider  
void test(int i, double* f) as the the "best fit" function to be called.
Can anyone more knowledgeable in the C++ Standard point out which behaviour is corrent?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the fact that case1 and case 4 mismatch make be think clearly that there is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't name any standards, but let's see what the differences are:

> `[C++11: 4.10/1]:` A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*. Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification. *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 5.19/3]:` A literal constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, but not pointer type. An integral constant expression is a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type. *[..]*

And:

> `[C++03: 4.10/1]:` A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type. Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4).
>
> `[C++03: 5.19/2]:` Other expressions are considered constant-expressions only for the purpose of non-local static object initialization (3.6.2). Such constant expressions shall evaluate to one of the following:
>
> - a null pointer value (4.10),
> - a null member pointer value (4.11),
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - an address constant expression,
> - a reference constant expression,
> - an address constant expression for a complete object type, plus or minus an integral constant expression, or
> - a pointer to member constant expression.

The key here is that the standard language changed between C++03 and C++11, with the latter introducing the requirement that a null pointer constant of this form be a literal.

(They always needed to actually be constants and evaluate to 0, so you can remove `v2`, `v3`, `w2`  and `w3` from your testcase.)

A null pointer constant can convert to a `double*` more easily than going through your user-defined conversion, so…

**I believe MSVS is implementing the C++03 rules.**

Amusingly, though, if I put GCC in C++03 mode, its behaviour isn't changed, which is technically non-compliant. I suspect the change in the language stemmed from the behaviour of common implementations at the time, rather than the other way around. I *can* see some [evidence that GCC was [allegedly] non-conforming in this regard as early as 2004](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#456), so it may also just be that the standard wording change fortuitously un-bugged what had been a GCC bug.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: can you put MSVC in a mode where it correctly follows C++11 rules? (Or how do they normally handle when a newer standard alters old behavior...)

Comment: @BrunoDeFraine: To the best of my knowledge, with MSVS you get whatever has been implemented against the most recent standard at the time of release and you can't switch between standards. So if MSVS implemented C++11 correctly in this regard, it would already do so and you wouldn't be able to turn that off.

Comment: Regarding the "evidence" link: GCC as old as 4.1.2 accepts the code specified there (not in C++11 mode of course, gcc 4.1.2 didn't even have one), so something changed after 2004? But it seems they only changed it for int/bool, not for an enum.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why doesn't `test(4, aaa);` display `WRONG` ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Good question

Comment: Interestingly, if I `extern` `v1`, *and* set the value below the usage, it no longer selects the `double*` overload.  If I cast `v1` (declared as in the OP's example) to non-const, and set the value to something else, cruelly, it selects the `double*` overload, and will have a non-zero value when called!

It seems like a bug that `aaa` does not trigger the pointer overload, yet `v1` and `w1` do as the former is truly a compile-time constant, whereas the latter are merely `const`.

Comment: @cyberbisson: That's barmy.